# SQL Query about percentage selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query for a condition:
If >=80 percent (4 or more rows as 4/5*100=80%) of the top 5 recent rows(by Date Column), for a KEY  have Value =A or =B, then change the flag from fail to pass for the entire KEY.
Here is the input and output sample:[image: Sample]

I have highlighted recent rows with green colour in the sample.
Can someone help me in this?

I tried till finding the top 5 recent rows by the foll code:

```
select * from(
select *, row_number() over (partition by "KEY") as 'RN' FROM (
select * from tb1
order by date desc))
where "RN"<=5
```

Couldnt figure what to be done after this

Comment: Group by KEY,DATE and use CASE based on COUNT(*)>4 for pass/fail and value

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far!?

Comment: To stand a better chance of any assistance, avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: *If >=80 percent .. for a KEY have Value =A or =B, then change the flag* Does all values must be the same? or 2*A+2*B+С matches too?

Comment: @Akina It should have only A or B.

Comment: @unclexo I tried till finding the top 5 recent rows by the foll code:select * from
select *, row_number() over (partition by "KEY") as 'RN' FROM (
select * from tb1
order by date desc)
where "RN"<=5

Couldnt figure what should be done after this

Comment: @Ayn76 You should write it down in your question section.

Comment: @unclexo Yes edited now

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina 5.7 version

Comment: *5.7 version* ??? You have told above that you have used ROW_NUMBER() in your attempts: *I tried till finding the top 5 recent rows by the foll code: `select * from select *, row_number() over (partition by "KEY") as 'RN' FROM ( select * from tb1 order by date desc) where "RN"<=5`*

Comment: MySQL5.7 doesn't have ROW_NUMBER. Either you didn't try ROW_NUMBER, or you're not using MySQL5.7

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

```sql
WITH 

-- enumerate rows per key group 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `key` ORDER BY `date` DESC) rn
          FROM sourcetable ),

-- take 5 recent rows only, check there are at least 4 rows with A/B 
cte2 AS ( SELECT `key`
          FROM cte1
          WHERE rn <= 5
          GROUP BY `key`
          HAVING (    SUM(`value` = 'A') >= 4 
                   OR SUM(`value` = 'B') >= 4 )
          -- AND SUM(rn = 5) )

-- update rows with found key values
UPDATE sourcetable
  JOIN cte2 USING (`key`)
SET flag = 'PASS';
```

---

> 5.7 version – Ayn76

Convert CTEs to subqueries. Emulate ROW_NUMBER() using user-defined variable.

Comment: @MatBailie OP tells explicitly: ".. 4 or more rows ..".

Comment: @MatBailie Also `'A3'` and  `'A4'` in shown sample data matches described situation, and they are not updated.

Comment: @MatBailie My solution have backward issue - if there is only 4 rows, and all of them are A (or B) they'll be updated which may be wrong. Let's wait OP...

Comment: Its 80% or more, which means out of 5 matches, 4 or more as 4/5*100 = 80%. A3 AND A4 does not matches the criteria of 5 matches, as each KEy has only a single record.

Comment: @Ayn76 Does this means that when total amount of rows with some `key` is 4 then these rows must NOT be updated anycase? even when all 4 rows are `value='A'`?

Comment: No the minimum number of records should be 5.

Comment: @Ayn76 Ifso then uncomment `AND SUM(rn = 5)`